# SmartGWT: ListGrid should grow only as per the number of records

Tags: smartgwt

I am using ListGrid in SmartGWT.
I don't want to set height of grid in advance as I dont know the number of records in the DataSource.

So, the requirement is:
If there are less than 10 records, grid's height would be in proportion with the number and if number of records are greater than 10, I will use pagination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never Mind. I found one such example here:
http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#grid_autofit_rows

Comment: I found one more example which better suited to my need.  http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#grid_autofit_filter